# Can not connect by ssh between nodes

Tags: ssh, debian, cluster-computing, nodes, proxmox

I have 5 Proxmox nodes with debian, we had some power problems and all nodes went down. The nodes at this time cannot ssh between them... From my computer I can access all of them but from one node to another takes too long and appears disconnected...

Any one had this problem?
Tks.

Comment: I have some experience. 1. check your firewall  2. check your ssh service. 3. check your hostfile in /etc/

Comment: Can you ping one node from another? at least to check if they are responisve or not... Do you have any firewall in place? If yes, please check the firewall rules